# Get a shortened (minimalist) link to a Google search

Tags: google, privacy, url-shortening

Sometimes, I want a shortened link to the results of a Google Search, to share in a comment on facebook or in a forum. A URL shortener (e.g., bit.ly) is not great, because the resulting Google Search link contains many details I may not want to share. For example, when I'm logged into Google, the resulting URL for a search contains all kinds of stuff like which browser was used (e.g., `sourceid=chrome-instant`), the language of my browser, as well as some details I'm not even able to grok.

Is there an easy way to get a *minimalist* URL for the results of a search, say for the keywords `prezi.com server problems` **without manually editing the resulting URL**?

Sub-question: is any of the data in a Google URL from a search private/confidential? That is, what would a bit.ly of a Google Search result for a logged-in user reveal about the user if he shared that link?

---

EDIT: Someone has [demystified the Google search URL parameters](http://www.blueglass.com/blog/google-search-url-parameters-query-string-anatomy/), and at least some of the data ("suggestion tracking") that's in there might be seen as revealing more info than one realizes. So, I'd say that doing a bit.ly of a search result could share more info than you want with other people. It could, for example, reveal *"the words/letters at which point the user stopped typing in the search box and instead went to suggest box and choose the entry."* (the `oq=` parameter).

Comment: I'm not sure that this is actually a valid thing to do, if you are logged in. By definition, when you are logged in to Google you are getting search results that are personal to you, based on your search-history, cookies on your machine, and goodness only knows what else. While I can understand that you want to share the specific results that you get - because someone else won't get the same ones - it seems to me that this is defeating the purpose of personalised search. OTOH, if you don't care so much about personal results, try www.LMGTFY.com ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [www.LMGTFY.com](http://www.LMGTFY.com)?

I'm not sure if it sends your personal search results. But it does rather humourously educate people about how to find the answers to their own questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a link like so for your search "prezi.com server problems" :

> https://www.google.com/search?q=prezi.com+server+problems&oq=prezi.com+server+problems&sugexp=chrome,mod=11&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=prezi.com+server+problems&oq=prezi.com+server+problems&sugexp=chrome,mod%3D11&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&pws=1&bpcl=37189454&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=4c16cf081dfc12af&biw=1366&bih=653

I'd simply just remove the information that is after the first and(&) symbol. So your search url would look like so:

> https://www.google.com/search?q=prezi.com+server+problems

It doesn't take much time at all to do this, hopefully it's not too big of a hassle. Also Google is not dumb, they know people share search links, therefore the URL's do not contain any private information, nor would that be secure.

Comment: The OP does explicitly ask for a solution "without manually editing the resulting URL"

Comment: -1 for suggesting editing the URL.  Also, I found [this page](http://www.blueglass.com/blog/google-search-url-parameters-query-string-anatomy/) that states "suggest tracking" info is in the URL parameters. Seems that might be confidential.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this specialized Google search URL shortener service:

[http://gog.is/](http://gogglis.appspot.com/)

Simply add your search query after and it will redirect to google

For example: gog.is/prezi.com,server,problems

**Update**: You could also use a bookmarklet to clean up the URL like this one:
https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/search.html#@google

Comment: How can I get there after an omnibox search in chrome? It seems like this is URL creating (editing).

Comment: I added a link to a nice bookmarlket. Just drag and drop the link to your favorites and click it when you're on the search result page.

Comment: The @google bookmarklet doesn't work as you say (at least in Chrome). It takes me to my iGoogle page with no search at all. Remember, I'm "logged in" to Google.